# how do i send all item id at once through url success.php?id=

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

As i add some items in the cart i cant change the status in the database from "ADDED TO CART " to "CONFIRMED"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php
require 'includes/common.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
    header('location: index.php');
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <!--jQuery library--> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Latest compiled a>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">nd minified JavaScript--> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Lifestyle Store | Products</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body >
          <?php
        include 'includes/header.php';
        ?>
        <?php
        $user_id=$_SESSION['id'];
        //changed from above user_id to $_getc ['user_id']
        $items_query="SELECT items.id,items.name,items.price from items INNER JOIN user_items INNER JOIN users ON items.id=user_items.item_id AND user_items.user_id=users.id WHERE user_items.user_id= $user_id AND user_items.status='Added To Cart'";
        
        // chaged from select * from user_items inner join items on user_items.item_id=items.id where items.id=$user_id";
        
        $items_query_result= mysqli_query($con, $items_query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
        
        
        
        ?>
        
       
       
        
       <?php  if (mysqli_num_rows($items_query_result)==0){ ?> 
       <?php echo 'Add something in cart';  }  else  { ?>
        <div class="container">
             <div class="row decor_bg">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                
                             
                             
                                <th>Item Number</th>
                                <th>Item Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Total</th>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                         
                        <tbody>
                            <?php 
                           
                                $total=0;
                                    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($items_query_result)) {  
                                        $total+=$row['price'];
                                        
                                          
                                                                                             ?>
                        
                            <tr>
                                
                                    <td><?php echo $row['id']  ?> </td> <td >  <?php echo $row['name'];   ?> <a href="cart-remove.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class='remove_item_link ' style="color:#e53939">Remove </a> </td>   <td> Rs. <?php   echo $row['price']; } ?>  </td><td> Rs. <?php echo $total;?>  <a href="success.php?id=" class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm Order</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                             <?php }?>
       
             <?php 
        include 'includes/footer.php';
        ?>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

1. **this is the code for a shopping cart**
2. **user add some this in the cart**
3. **then when the user goes to the cart the cart displays all the items with their ids, name and the price **
4. **and finally the total price**
5. **i have defined a while loop to sum up the price and to display the id name etc **
6. **now i want to send the item id to the success.php to change the status in the database from "Added To Cart " to "Confirmed"**

Comment: UPDATE ... WHERE user AND status ?

Comment: scroll to right you will see`<a href="success.php?id=" class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm Order</a> ` what should i pass as the value of id so that i can confirm all items of the cart in the database

Comment: @NabhdeepChaudhary You want specific id of a product correct? by which you can update status of specific product ?

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATED]** You can stored the ids in one variable.

```
 <?php         
     $total=0;
     $ids = '';
     while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($items_query_result)) {  
         $total+=$row['price'];
         if(strlen($ids)== 0){
            $ids = $row['id'];
         }else{
           $ids = ','.$row['id'];
         }
 ?>       
  <tr>

      <td><?php echo $row['id']  ?> </td>
      <td >  <?php echo $row['name'];   ?>
             <a href="cart-remove.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class='remove_item_link ' style="color:#e53939">
                 Remove 
             </a> 
      </td> 
      <td> Rs. <?php   echo $row['price']; } ?>  </td>
      <td> Rs. <?php echo $total;?>  
          <a href="success.php?id=<?php echo $ids;?>" class='btn btn-primary'>
            Confirm Order
          </a>
      </td>
```

Then in your `success.php` you can explode the `$ids` like this:

```
$ids = explode(",",$_GET['id'])); //with explode you can get splits the ids

for($i=0; $i<count($ids); $i++){
   $final_id = $ids[$i];
  //then here you can do the update sql query then the row id is the `final_id` in every loop you will update the database.
}
```

hope it will help!

Comment: if you are thinking of while loop.. it ends at `</td>   <td> Rs. <?php   echo $row['price']; } ?>  </td><td> Rs.`

Comment: So it is not only one id that you can update on the database but all of the ids that are included to the loop right?

Comment: all the ids included in the loop

Comment: error  `Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp64\www\project\cart.php on line 76`

Comment: and if i try to remove `strlen` from `if` it runs but the items confirm one by one **means i have to go back in cart the confirm other items**..... i have to confirm all items  at once

Comment: Oh sorry just replace the `strlen` to `count` it should be work  by doing it

Comment: no sill not worked.. still it is confirming items one by one

Comment: Oh my mistake remove the `$ids` variable before the `if()` statement...wait i will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
<?php 
    $total=0;
    while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($items_query_result)) {  
        $total+=$row['price'];  
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $row['id'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $row['name'];
        echo '<a href="cart-remove.php?id='.$row['id'].'" class='remove_item_link ' style="color:#e53939">Remove </a>'; 
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "Rs ".$row['price'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "Rs ".$total;
            echo '<a href="success.php?id=" class='btn btn-primary'>Confirm Order</a>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
     } ?>  
</tbody>
```

try this it will work, I have corrected your iteration closing end. go through it.

Comment: no id didn't worked ` echo '<a href="cart-remove.php?id='.<?php echo $row['id']; ?>.'" class='remove_item_link ' style="color:#e53939">Remove </a>';`      syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Sorry I have made a syntax mistake, now try it, hope it will work now